# How can I make this SQL trigger work without 'returning' a result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want MySQL triggers to automatically perform certain actions, rather than put that in the application logic.

The approach is roughly this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertAction AFTER INSERT
ON UserAction
FOR EACH ROW CALL CreateAutomaticResponse(...);
```

Which uses

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateAutomaticResponse (...)
     INSERT INTO SomeTable (foo, bar)
     VALUES
     (
          SELECT x FROM SomeTable ...
          ...
     )
```

Now this creates an error

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000) at line 1675: You can't specify target table 'SomeTable' for update in FROM clause
```

I believe the solution is to do something like this

```
 SELECT @tmp := x FROM SomeTable ...
 INSERT INTO SomeTable (foo, bar) VALUES (@tmp, ...)
```

The trouble with this is I then get

```
ERROR 1415 (0A000) at line 1666: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

It seems to be the `SELECT @tmp := ...` line which causes this.

As far as I am concerned, this procedure is not returning anything, despite the `SELECT`, because it's only selecting into a temporary variable.

Can I tell MySQL to consider the procedure to be not returning anything? Or otherwise fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `INSERT INTO sometable(foo, bar)
  SELECT x, y
  FROM sometable`

Comment: `You can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part`. You are clearly doing this in the `INSERT` statement. Solution is do not use nested sub-queries and execute it in different parts... On another note, the second error `Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger` is clearly because you can't execute `SELECT` statements from the trigger. If you want to set the variables, use `SELECT INTO`... Also, great question I would like to say!

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO ... SELECT worked.